# How to forget wifi in version 12.1.2

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi

I changed the password of my school account, so I can't connect to the school wifi anymore. Normally, there would be an option to forget wifi, but that doesn't seem to exist in iOS 12.1.2. Selecting the school wifi does not prompt me to re-enter my password but simply says "unable to connect". I am aware that I can reset all my network settings, but I don't want to deal with remembering the passwords of other wifi I typically connect to. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Settings -> Wi-Fi -> Click the info button to the right of the network you want to forget. There's a "Forget this Network" choice at the top.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but there is no such option. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: I just checked a 12.1.1 and 12.1.3 iOS device (1 of each). I have that option on those networks I know I've used in the past, and not on the one I didn't recognize.

Comment: I did a chat with apple support and they were surprised it wasn't there. But it's a wifi I used before, and it definitely doesn't appear. It may be the way the school set up the wifi. They suggested me to install the update to see if that solves the problem.